# Is using the Force like using a muscle?

Tags: star-wars

When you work out your muscles, they get stronger. When a person keeps practicing using the Force everyday, will they get stronger in its use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As depicted in the movies, learning to use the Force is more like learning a martial art than simply building up a muscle.  Physical conditioning is clearly part of the training, as we saw Luke running through the jungle on Dagobah with Yoda on his back exhorting him.  But it's also a mental discipline that must be mastered through expert instruction and practice.

Comment: Good point. Martial arts isn't about strength at all.

Comment: +1 | Not true Donmax. Some martial arts depend on strength to enhance the performance of the art. Karate is very much a martial art where the strength of the artist is a factor in how well the art can be performed. In Karate, you are always attacking, even when you block. Your blocks are strong and designed to damage the attacker. Strength matters significantly in Karate. Much less so in an art such as Wing Chun where speed, a sense of the movement of the opponent and balance play an equally important role, far less than raw strength.

Comment: My vote took you to 10,000 Kyle. It was an honor to promote your work.

Comment: @Thaddeus Compliment appreciated and returned; I'm an admirer of your answers here.

Comment: I don't know how cannon it is, but I can recall from a number of the books Luke discussing the problem of Jedi bodies atrophying because they don't exercise their body enough, being too busy focusing on the force powers. I think the scenes of Luke exercising in the movies was more about learning to focus despite numerous distractions, such as a spiked heart rate. No references, just what I remember from a dozen or so books.

Comment: As someone who had a black belt at 11, 30 years ago, I can safely say that it is the skeleto-muscular coordination that is the important factor, not the size of the muscle. As Bruce Lee discovered, muscle size was relatively unimportant which is why he kept himself small, toned, and quick.